# Issue when Oracle SQL processes JSON with same entry names

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I'm trying to get some data from a JSON file and store those data in a different format in Oracle. Currently I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE json_documents (
  id    RAW(16) NOT NULL,
  data  CLOB,
  CONSTRAINT json_documents_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT json_documents_json_chk CHECK (data IS JSON)
);
```

And I made the following insert:

```
INSERT INTO json_documents (id, data)
VALUES (SYS_GUID(),
  '[{  
      "rid7":"9R1CODE",
      "rid":[  

      ]
   },
   {  
      "rid7":"ZB0CODE",
      "rid":[  
         {  
            "rid10":"WB10123124",
            "rid17":"WB10123124ZB0CODE"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "rid7":"ZB1CODE",
      "rid":[  
         {  
            "rid10":"ZKH9875435",
            "rid17":"ZKH9875435ZB1CODE"
         }
      ]
   }]');
```

Now if I execute the following select:

```
SELECT a.data.rid7
FROM JSON_DOCUMENTS a;
```

I get the following result:

```
[9R1CODE,ZB0CODE,ZB1CODE]
```

while I would like to get the results in one column, but in different rows.
Is there a way to do that? How can I distinguish between multiple "rid7" in the same row in my `json_documents` table?

Also how can I access to the different "rid10" I have in my JSON file?

I tried also to use `json_value` in the following way:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(a.data, '$.rid7')
FROM JSON_DOCUMENTS a;
```

but the query resulted into a null value. Why?

Answer (score 1):

you can use json_table for this purpose. NESTED PATH parameter does the trick.

please check my answer according to your acquired result.

```
select CONDITION from 
  json_table('{"test": ["9R1CODE","ZB0CODE","ZB1CODE"]}', '$' 
  columns (test varchar2(100) format json path '$',
    nested path '$.test[*]'
      columns (  condition varchar2(100)  path '$')));
```

for your second question, you can use

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(a.data, '$.*.rid10')
FROM JSON_DOCUMENTS a;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first part of your answer does the trick pretty good for what I need but the second part won't work: in fact your code returns only the first rid10 that it finds, while I want them all to structure them in a second time in a way similar as you did for the rid7.